# Prove that $b^2\gt 4ac \implies ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two distinct real roots.

Tags: proof-writing, quadratics

How to do this in the method of a conditional proof? Assuming only $b^2\gt 4ac$ how to arrive at the conclusion without manipulating $ax^2+bx+c=0$ to yield the quadratic equation?

Comment: Put $x=-b/2a{}$?

Comment: Do you know how to derive a formula for the roots of this quadratic polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by method of conditional proof? You'll always have to do some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: If the discriminant is positive, that immediately yields two different  real roots

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My guess is he means direct proof. No logical shenanigans like proof by contradiction or by contrapositive.

Comment: @AlvinLepik that's what I meant.

Comment: @Fakemistake yes. I want to know if it is possible to prove that the quadratic has two distinct roots without deriving a formula.

Comment: No such proof is possible because it can happen that $b^2>4ac$ and yet the equation has only one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to manipulate the equation at some point.

By completing the square and rearranging, you obtain the implication
$$ax^2+bx+c=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x \in \left\{ \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \right\}$$

By substituting those values into the equation you obtain the $\Leftarrow$ direction.

Thus we have the equivalence
$$ax^2+bx+c=0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \in \left\{ \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \right\}$$
without needing the assumption that $b^2>4ac$.

The assumption that $b^2 > 4ac$ tells you that the two solutions are real and distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Write the equation $ax^2 +bx+c=0$ as

$$(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2 + (\frac{c}{a} - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}) =0$$

which is easily verified by multiplying out.

So the quadratic has two real solutions iff

$$(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2  = \frac{b^2}{4a^2} - \frac{c}{a} = \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}$$

has $2$ real solutions.

Which is the case iff the fraction on the RHS is $>0$ so iff $b^2-4c >0$.
(Based ultimately on the fact that $y^2=d$ has two real solutions iff $d>0$ and that $4a^2 >0$ and so does not affect the sign of the fraction).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write the given equation in the form
$$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=0$$ for $a\neq 0$